# Does P(A|B)*P(B|A) give us anything significant?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was thinking about how P(A and B) = P(A)*P(B|A), but I'm wondering what, if anything, P(A|B)*P(B|A) gives us. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have

$$P(B \mid A) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$$

Similarly,

$$P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$

So the product is just

$$P(A \mid B)P(B \mid A) = \frac{(P(A \cap B))^2}{P(A)P(B)} \geq 0.$$

Observe that 
$$P(A \mid B)P(B \mid A) \leq 1,$$ as we have
$$A \cap B \subset A \Longrightarrow P(A \cap B) \leq P(A)$$
and
$$A \cap B \subset B \Longrightarrow P(A \cap B) \leq P(B).$$

Note that, if $A$ and $B$ are independent events, then
$$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$$
so that we obtain
$$P(A \mid B)P(B \mid A) = P(A)P(B) = P(A \cap B).$$

If $A$ and $B$ were mutually exclusive events (so that $P(A \cap B) = 0$), then 
$$P(A \mid B) = 0$$
and
$$P(B \mid A) = 0$$
are both true.

Comment: Great, thanks so much for the answer. So I understand the part about mutual exclusive events, but I don't understand why P(A∣B)P(B∣A)=P(A)P(B)=P(A∩B).

Comment: @rb612, that relationship holds if $A$ and $B$ are **independent events**, and it follows from the equation
$$P(A \mid B)P(B \mid A) = \frac{(P(A \cap B))^2}{P(A)P(B)},$$
and
$$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B),$$
since $A$ and $B$ are assumed to be independent events.

Comment: Oh that makes sense now! Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome!  Glad to be of help. =)